# How to force the creation of a NEW DATABASE CONNECTION using PHP's PDO to connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, connection

I use PHP to connect to MySQL.

At last, I switched to the **PDO** interface from the deprecated **mysql_**!  I love it, and it works great, but one lingering issue...

**MY QUESTION**: Does a `new PDO` (using the same credentials) always create a *new connection* to the database?
If that's the case, then I'm all set!
I am aware of the option of "Persistent connections" in PDO; I do *NOT* use that option.

With the old mysql_connect() function, I could FORCE a new database connection with the **new_link** flag.  Am I correct in my understanding that with a `new PDO`, one ALWAYS gets a new database connection?  (Unless requesting a "persistent connection" - which, once again, I do NOT do.)

If I understand correctly, PDO is the opposite of mysql_connect in that (assuming identical database credentials) PDO always gives a new connection, unless specified otherwise (i.e. unless requesting a "persistent connection") - WHEREAS by default mysql_connect would give the same old connection, unless you forced a new one.

---

Side note: as to WHY I want to force a new connection, it's part of my implementation of a more **robust** SQL query execution mechanism.  I discovered over the years that, when a PHP script is used to serve large files, occasionally a new SQL query gets a *lost database connection error* ("the database has gone away"); in those cases, my remedy - which worked perfectly  for years - has been the following algorithm:
1) try to run the SQL query
2) in case of error, force a new database connection [critical step!] and then re-run the SQL query.  It if fails a 2nd time, give up and issue an error/log; but, in most cases, the problem goes away and the 2nd attempt works :)

I'm trying to replicate that robust function with PDO...  I found excellent guides on the mysql -> PDO switching (such as http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers ), but I'm still hazy whether instantiating a new PDO object implies a new database connection in cases where an earlier PDO object was created with the same credentials.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's a new instances of the connection using the credentials given. You can see this with MySQL SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST via MySQL command-line, as it creates each new connection and query, just have to be fast about it or run some slow queries.

On a side note; running the insert again is a bit dirty workaround to an unoptimized process with the database design and mysql config, I recommend revisiting the items in question and find a better method to the process. Best